# lambda iterative query dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I would like to pass to lambda an array of ids format of "uuid-mm-yyyy". I have 2 questions: 1 on lambda and 1 on DynamoDB.

Lambda: How does lambda iteratively update dynamodb table with this GSI in dynamodb table? It seems lambda can update 1 at a time but I can't find any example to iteratively update based on input array and return an array of results. To Update I found to use UpdateItem. Desire behavior is to update if exists and add if not.

DynamoDB: Currently my DynamoDB table has attributes: id, propertyId, month, year. I added the GSI propertyId-month-year with value like above(uuid-mm-yyyy) so that I can uniquely query the DB knowing those 3 values. If there is a better way to design my table, please feel free to advise as well for uniquely querying on uuid, month, and year. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide more context for your question. What are you trying to do? What does your table structure look like so far? Are you asking a question about DynamoDB or Lambda?

Comment: Thank you Matthew for your suggestion. I've updated my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding DDB please use unique partition key will be more helpful for querying data. Else it will be a scan.
You can have an attribute in DDB schema like "partitionKey" and it's value might be "id||propertyId".
for monthYear: it won't be good to store the epoch timestamp?

Comment: Thank you Sigcout! I can have partition key of propertyId and sort key of timestampDue as epoch timestamp. But what is the dynamodb sdk function that I could use to update if both matches and add if it doesn't?

Comment: `UpdateItem` performs an “Upsert”. If the primary key doesn’t exist, it will insert the item, and if it does exist, it will update the item.

Comment: Thank you! How do you call that iteratively over a range of primary keys?

Comment: Or is it better to make a new API call to trigger lambda update for each GSI id? I would think we want to make 1 API call with array of IDs then let lambda iteratively update the DB. Please advise. Thank you!